# What is the right way to escape a backslash at the end of a csv field?

Tags: php, csv, format, escaping, standards

I have this array: `array("\\","hi")` and want to convert it to csv format to read it back. Thus, I wrote the following shell script command:

```
php -r 'fputcsv(fopen("php://stdout","w"),array("\\","hi"));' |\
php -r 'print_r(fgetcsv(fopen("php://stdin","r")));'
```

But unfortunately, the output of this is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => \",hi

)
```

Which obviously doesn't have anything to do with the original array given. Sorry to say I'm not surprised about the inconsistency of `fgetcsv`/`fputcsv`. What would be an algorithm to do this right?

In case anyone is wondering:

```
PHP 5.4.45-0+deb7u2 (cli) (built: Oct 17 2015 08:26:31)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: You need to change the escape character if you want to use \ in the content which can be set on both the get and put functions.

Comment: Note that the escape char argument for fputcsv() requires PHP >= 5.5.4 - [Demo](https://3v4l.org/IQqu5)

Comment: Why? Why doesn't ```\``` get escaped too? How do you choose a different escape character and keep the csv file portable?

Comment: @AndrasGyomrey CSV isn't really as portable as it's supposed - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values - even the separator you use will need to vary from locale to locale

Comment: Excel saves ```array(";\","hi")``` as ```";\";hi```. To make it at least read an excel CSV saved file, I'm screwed with ```fgetcsv```.

Comment: The closest to a standard definition for a CSV is [RFC 4180](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) but that's simply because it's consistent with most US implementations, not the reverse

Comment: I'll write my own encoder/decoder based on that document. Thanks.